# getting stuck in replacing stopwords(txt.file) from data stored as list fetched from database

Tags: java

Kindly view code at for loop part where using replace method 
I am Unable to replace stop words from data I have fetched from data base.
error shows  ,array bound exception:1.

Kindly view code at for loop part where using replace method 
I am Unable to replace stop words from data I have fetched from data base.
error shows  ,array bound exception:1.
Kindly view code at for loop part where using replace method 
I am Unable to replace stop words from data I have fetched from data base.
error shows  ,array bound exception:1.

I amunable to resolve it ,give me some suggestion

```
package chatbot;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class keywords{

     private static Scanner scan2;
     private static final String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String QUER = null;
     //private static final String SCOR = null;
    // private static final String SCORE = 
    private static final String ANSW = null;


     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

              Connection con = null;
              Statement stmnt = null;
              ResultSet result = null;

              Set<String> list1= new HashSet<>();
              try {
                        Class.forName(driverName);
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.144.97.144:1521:NQLDEV", "DEVNQL", "DEVNQL");
                        stmnt = con.createStatement();
                        System.out.println("Connection established");

                        List<String> rsl1 = new ArrayList<>();

                        List<String> rsl3 = new ArrayList<>();

                        String query = "SELECT * FROM DEVNQL.CHATKEY";

                        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query);


                        while (rs.next()) {
                            rsl1.add(rs.getString(1));
                            rsl3.add(rs.getString(3));
                     }
                        //System.out.println("result "+rsl1    + "   "+rsl3);


                        File file = new File("M:\\Documents\\stop-word-list.txt");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        String st;
                        while((st=br.readLine()) != null){

                    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(st));
                            //List<String> ux = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(st));


                    for(int i=0;i<rsl1.size()-1;i++){

                            for(String n:wordList)

                           if(rsl1.contains(n.getBytes()[i])){
                                                          rsl1.get(i).replace(n.charAt(i)+"\\rsl1+", "");
                              //note this will remove spaces at the end
                         }
                      }
                       System.out.println(rsl1);
                        }}



                    // for (int i=0;i<=rsl1.size()-1;i++){





                            /*
                                 for (String removeword:wordList){

                                 System.out.println("removeword  "+removeword+  "  "+rsl1.get(i)+
                                         "    "+rsl1.get(i).contains(removeword));
                                 rsl1.get(i).replace("hi","abcd********");
                                     if (rsl1.get(i).contains(removeword)) {

                                         rsl1.get(i).replace("hi","abcd********");
                               } // end if
                      } // end for
*/          //  } // end for

                       // System.out.println("result   "+rsl1);
                      //  }
           //   System.out.println("replace   "+rsl1.get(0).replace("hi", "abcde"));          

           //   }



                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.exit(1);
                   } 

              fi`enter code here`nally {
                            if (stmnt != null) {
                                     stmnt.close();
                            }

                        if (con != null) {
                                 con.close();
                        }
              }
       }}
```

Comment: Can you please delete the repeated part of your question and fix the indendation in your code?

Comment: The way you've formatted  your code here makes it very difficult to read, but it looks to me like you're creating a brand new list of words for every line in the file, with just one element in it.  Instead, you should have just one list, that you add each word to in turn.

Comment: If you want people to help you on Stack Overflow, it's a good idea to make your code as tidy as possible - don't have extra bits that are commented out and don't have wild spacing.  Also, if you can provide as much information as possible about what your inputs and outputs are, and what actually went wrong, that helps too.  If you make it difficult for people to help you, they'll just move on to the next question.

Comment: `fi`enter code here`nally` - wild

Comment: kindly accept my answer - it is a bit rude just to dump your question here for people to spend time on and you do not even do so much as to make a comment

Answer (score 1):

replace actually returns a new String as in Java Strings are immutatable

so

```
String newString =  rsl1.get(i).replace(n.charAt(i)+"\\rsl1+", "");
```